# How do you create a flag that takes the value of column value depending whether the values make up the majority of the count?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this...

```
id    city        date
1     chicago     5/1
1     chicago     5/2
1     new york    5/1
2     new york    5/3
2     seattle      .
3     chicago      .
4     seattle      .
4     seattle      .
```

And I want to create a third column that takes the value of 'city' where the specific city makes up the majority (>51%) of the number of entries a single ID has. So for example, id #1 would have favorite_city = 'chicago'. I'm not sure where to even start...

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Side note - I have separate logic that I've written out to take care of IDs that do not have a majority or not enough count to create a majority.

Comment: So the new column will have the value of `chicago` of the first 3 rows, is that what you want ?

Comment: Correct. In the rest of my code though, I will be selecting distinct ID and adding this variable on as a part of a 'case when' statement.

Comment: Window function can be a solution. Or you can write a procedure to calculate the favorite city for each id. Depends on your situation, it can be faster than expensive queries.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only query - no write access to this DB.

Comment: The definition of majority here is incorrect.  It should be >50%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH
  summary As
(
  SELECT
    your_table.*,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id)  AS id_count,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, city)  AS id_city_count
  FROM
    your_table
)
SELECT
  summary.*,
  MAX(
    CASE WHEN id_city_count * 2 > id_count THEN city ELSE NULL END
  ) 
  OVER (PARTITION BY id)
FROM
  summary
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine but gives all cities (not unique one) for id which have equal count of cities,

```
with a as( select * from (
select id, city, nb, 
     rank() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY nb DESC) as rnk
from(
select id, city, count(city) nb 
  from test
group by id, city)as t group by id, city,nb) as tt where rnk =1)
select test.id as id, test.city as city, a.city as favcity from
test, a where test.id= a.id
```

Life demo and output [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/247b4/19)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already added new column to your table (which name in my example is `test`) you can run:

```
update test t
    set t.favorite_city= 
        case
            when 
                (select c.count from (select count(1) from test t_freq where t_freq.id=t.id group by city) as c order by 1 desc limit 1)/ 
                (select count(1) from test t_all where t_all.id=t.id) > 0.5
            then 
                (select c.city from (select count(1), city from test t_freq where t_freq.id=t.id group by city) as c order by 1 desc limit 1)
            else
                null
        end;
```